# NLOG ORA-01036 illegal variable name/number ошибка

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, nlog

Выдает такую вот ошибку, кол-во переменных у меня правильное, как и название.
Вот запрос:

```
<target name="database"
      xsi:type="Database"
      dbProvider="System.Data.OracleClient"
      connectionString="Data Source="..."
      commandText="INSERT INTO SYS_LOGGING(DT, SRVC, LVL, CLLST, MSG) VALUES(@time_stamp, @service, @level, @call_site, @message)">
  <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}"/>
  <parameter name="@service" layout="${basedir}" />
  <parameter name="@level" layout="${uppercase:${level}}"/>
  <parameter name="@call_site" layout="${callsite:fileName=true:includeSourcePath=false:cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates=true:skipFrames=2}"/>
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
</target>
```

Вот база:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы посмотрели, что получается из запроса после всех подстановок... ну или что за запрос приходит на сервер...

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том что не указал в запросе пользователя\схему базы, к примеру:

```
 commandText="INSERT INTO BASE.SYS_LOGGING(DT, SRVC, LVL, CLLST, MSG) VALUES(@time_stamp, @service, @level, @call_site, @message)">
```

Comment: "не указал в запросе название базы" - а где оно сейчас указано?

Comment: Это не "база", а схема/пользователь. Указывать лучше всегда (на всякий пожарный), но можно не указывать, если запрос выполняется от того же пользователя. Т. е. если бы вы залогинились от имени пользователя `BASE`, запрос бы прошел в первоначальном виде.